# What am I liable for with a rental property?

Tags: rent

I have signed a contract with 5 of my friends at university for a 6 bed flat. I have decided to withdraw from the uni and therefor do not need the flat, if I just never turn up and never pay anything what am I liable for/what could they do. I have paid a £300 deposit.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the lease, but generally speaking you would be liable for your portion of the rent for the duration of the lease. So if you were supposed to pay £300 a month for 12 month, £3600 is what you owe. If the tenants are jointly and severally liable for the money, the landlord will probably collect from the remaining tenants, and they might sue you for your share. They may have to sue you, if they aren't allowed to replace you (to sublet). If this is university housing only available to university students, there is probably a clause covering the situation where a tenant drops out or never enrolls in the first place. You basically have to read the lease, but just not showing up is not a legal way of extinguishing your contractual obligation.

Comment: thank you, for some reason my dad (a part time landlord in his own right) thought that id only be liable for the deposit although he hasn't had the opportunity to read the contract yet. I think he's going to get a friend who's a solicitor to have a look at the contract but I wanted to see what I could find in the mean time